# How to decrease the time spent on one instruction?

Tags: c, optimization, x86-64, perf

I am trying to optimize a code in C, and it seems that one instruction is taking about 22% of the time.

The code is compiled with gcc 8.2.0.  Flags are `-O3 -DNDEBUG -g`, and `-Wall -Wextra -Weffc++ -pthread -lrt`.

```
    509529.517218      task-clock (msec)         #    0.999 CPUs utilized
            6,234      context-switches          #    0.012 K/sec
               10      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec
        1,305,885      page-faults               #    0.003 M/sec
1,985,640,853,831      cycles                    #    3.897 GHz                      (30.76%)
1,897,574,410,921      instructions              #    0.96  insn per cycle           (38.46%)
  229,365,727,020      branches                  #  450.152 M/sec                    (38.46%)
   13,027,677,754      branch-misses             #    5.68% of all branches          (38.46%)
  604,340,619,317      L1-dcache-loads           # 1186.076 M/sec                    (38.46%)
   47,749,307,910      L1-dcache-load-misses     #    7.90% of all L1-dcache hits    (38.47%)
   19,724,956,845      LLC-loads                 #   38.712 M/sec                    (30.78%)
    3,349,412,068      LLC-load-misses           #   16.98% of all LL-cache hits     (30.77%)
  <not supported>      L1-icache-loads                                          
      129,878,634      L1-icache-load-misses                                         (30.77%)
  604,482,046,140      dTLB-loads                # 1186.353 M/sec                    (30.77%)
    4,596,384,416      dTLB-load-misses          #    0.76% of all dTLB cache hits   (30.77%)
        2,493,696      iTLB-loads                #    0.005 M/sec                    (30.77%)
       21,356,368      iTLB-load-misses          #  856.41% of all iTLB cache hits   (30.76%)
  <not supported>      L1-dcache-prefetches                                     
  <not supported>      L1-dcache-prefetch-misses                                

    509.843595752 seconds time elapsed

    507.706093000 seconds user
      1.839848000 seconds sys
```

VTune Amplifier gives me a hint to a function: https://pasteboard.co/IagrLaF.png

The instruction `cmpq` seems to take 22% of the whole time. On the other hand, the other instructions take negligible time.

`perf` gives me a somewhat different picture, yet I think that results are consistent:

```
 Percent│       bool mapFound = false;
   0.00 │       movb   $0x0,0x7(%rsp)
        │     goDownBwt():
        │       bwt_2occ(bwt, getStateInterval(previousState)->k-1, getStateInterval(previousState)->l, nucleotide, &newState->interval.k, &newState->interval.l);
   0.00 │       lea    0x20(%rsp),%r12
        │         newState->preprocessedInterval = previousState->preprocessedInterval->firstChild + nucleotide;
   0.00 │       lea    (%rax,%rax,2),%rax
   0.00 │       shl    $0x3,%rax
   0.00 │       mov    %rax,0x18(%rsp)
   0.01 │       movzwl %dx,%eax
   0.00 │       mov    %eax,(%rsp)
   0.00 │     ↓ jmp    d6
        │       nop
        │       if ((previousState->trace & PREPROCESSED) && (previousState->preprocessedInterval->firstChild != NULL)) {
   0.30 │ 88:   mov    (%rax),%rsi
   8.38 │       mov    0x10(%rsi),%rcx
   0.62 │       test   %rcx,%rcx
   0.15 │     ↓ je     1b0
        │         newState->preprocessedInterval = previousState->preprocessedInterval->firstChild + nucleotide;
   2.05 │       add    0x18(%rsp),%rcx
        │         ++stats->nDownPreprocessed;
   0.25 │       addq   $0x1,0x18(%rdx)
        │         newState->trace                = PREPROCESSED;
   0.98 │       movb   $0x10,0x30(%rsp)
        │         return (newState->preprocessedInterval->interval.k <= newState->preprocessedInterval->interval.l);
  43.36 │       mov    0x8(%rcx),%rax
   2.61 │       cmp    %rax,(%rcx)
        │         newState->preprocessedInterval = previousState->preprocessedInterval->firstChild + nucleotide;
   0.05 │       mov    %rcx,0x20(%rsp)
        │         return (newState->preprocessedInterval->interval.k <= newState->preprocessedInterval->interval.l);
   3.47 │       setbe  %dl
```

The function is

```
inline bool goDownBwt (state_t *previousState, unsigned short nucleotide, state_t *newState) {
  ++stats->nDown;
  if ((previousState->trace & PREPROCESSED) && (previousState->preprocessedInterval->firstChild != NULL)) {
    ++stats->nDownPreprocessed;
    newState->preprocessedInterval = previousState->preprocessedInterval->firstChild + nucleotide;
    newState->trace                = PREPROCESSED;
    return (newState->preprocessedInterval->interval.k <= newState->preprocessedInterval->interval.l);
  }
  bwt_2occ(bwt, getStateInterval(previousState)->k-1, getStateInterval(previousState)->l, nucleotide, &newState->interval.k, &newState->interval.l);
  newState->interval.k = bwt->L2[nucleotide] + newState->interval.k + 1;
  newState->interval.l = bwt->L2[nucleotide] + newState->interval.l;
  newState->trace = 0;
  return (newState->interval.k <= newState->interval.l);
}
```

`state_t` is defined as

```
struct state_t {
  union {
    bwtinterval_t interval;
    preprocessedInterval_t *preprocessedInterval;
  };
  unsigned char trace;
  struct state_t *previousState;
};
```

`preprocessedInterval_t` is:

```
struct preprocessedInterval_t {
  bwtinterval_t interval;
  preprocessedInterval_t *firstChild;
};
```

There are few (~1000) `state_t` structures.  However, there are many (350k) `preprocessedInterval_t` objects, allocated somewhere else.

The first `if` is true 15 billion times over 19 billions.

Finding mispredicted branches with `perf record -e branches,branch-misses mytool` on the function gives me:

```
Available samples
2M branches                                                                                                                                                                                                       
1M branch-misses
```

Can I assume that branch misprediction is responsible for this slow down?
What would be the next step to optimize my code?

The code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/mzytnicki/srnaMapper/tree/preprocess)

---

**Edit 1**

`valgrind --tool=cachegrind` gives me:

```
I   refs:      1,893,716,274,393
I1  misses:            4,702,494
LLi misses:              137,142
I1  miss rate:              0.00%
LLi miss rate:              0.00%

D   refs:        756,774,557,235  (602,597,601,611 rd   + 154,176,955,624 wr)
D1  misses:       39,489,866,187  ( 33,583,272,379 rd   +   5,906,593,808 wr)
LLd misses:        3,483,920,786  (  3,379,118,877 rd   +     104,801,909 wr)
D1  miss rate:               5.2% (            5.6%     +             3.8%  )
LLd miss rate:               0.5% (            0.6%     +             0.1%  )

LL refs:          39,494,568,681  ( 33,587,974,873 rd   +   5,906,593,808 wr)
LL misses:         3,484,057,928  (  3,379,256,019 rd   +     104,801,909 wr)
LL miss rate:                0.1% (            0.1%     +             0.1%  )
```

---

**Edit 2**

I compiled with `-O3 -DNDEBUG -march=native -fprofile-use`, and used the command `perf stat -etask-clock,context-switches,cpu-migrations,page-faults,cycles,branches,branch-misses,instructions,uops_issued.any,uops_executed.thread,mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss,mem_load_uops_retired.l2_miss,mem_load_uops_retired.l1_miss ./a.out`

```
    508322.348021      task-clock (msec)         #    0.998 CPUs utilized
           21,592      context-switches          #    0.042 K/sec
               33      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec
        1,305,885      page-faults               #    0.003 M/sec
1,978,382,746,597      cycles                    #    3.892 GHz                      (44.44%)
  228,898,532,311      branches                  #  450.302 M/sec                    (44.45%)
   12,816,920,039      branch-misses             #    5.60% of all branches          (44.45%)
1,867,947,557,739      instructions              #    0.94  insn per cycle           (55.56%)
2,957,085,686,275      uops_issued.any           # 5817.343 M/sec                    (55.56%)
2,864,257,274,102      uops_executed.thread      # 5634.726 M/sec                    (55.56%)
    2,490,571,629      mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss #    4.900 M/sec                    (55.55%)
   12,482,683,638      mem_load_uops_retired.l2_miss #   24.557 M/sec                    (55.55%)
   18,634,558,602      mem_load_uops_retired.l1_miss #   36.659 M/sec                    (44.44%)

    509.210162391 seconds time elapsed

    506.213075000 seconds user
      2.147749000 seconds sys
```

---

**Edit 3**

I selected the results of `perf record -etask-clock,context-switches,cpu-migrations,page-faults,cycles,branches,branch-misses,instructions,uops_issued.any,uops_executed.thread,mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss,mem_load_uops_retired.l2_miss,mem_load_uops_retired.l1_miss a.out` that mentioned my function:

```
Samples: 2M of event 'task-clock', Event count (approx.): 517526250000
Overhead  Command     Shared Object       Symbol
  49.76%  srnaMapper  srnaMapper          [.] mapWithoutError

Samples: 917K of event 'cycles', Event count (approx.): 891499601652
Overhead  Command     Shared Object       Symbol
  49.36%  srnaMapper  srnaMapper          [.] mapWithoutError

Samples: 911K of event 'branches', Event count (approx.): 101918042567
Overhead  Command     Shared Object       Symbol
  43.01%  srnaMapper  srnaMapper          [.] mapWithoutError

Samples: 877K of event 'branch-misses', Event count (approx.): 5689088740
Overhead  Command     Shared Object       Symbol
  50.32%  srnaMapper  srnaMapper          [.] mapWithoutError

Samples: 1M of event 'instructions', Event count (approx.): 1036429973874
Overhead  Command     Shared Object       Symbol
  34.85%  srnaMapper  srnaMapper          [.] mapWithoutError

Samples: 824K of event 'uops_issued.any', Event count (approx.): 1649042473560
Overhead  Command     Shared Object       Symbol
  42.19%  srnaMapper  srnaMapper          [.] mapWithoutError

Samples: 802K of event 'uops_executed.thread', Event count (approx.): 1604052406075
Overhead  Command     Shared Object       Symbol
  48.14%  srnaMapper  srnaMapper          [.] mapWithoutError

Samples: 13K of event 'mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss', Event count (approx.): 1350194507
Overhead  Command     Shared Object      Symbol
  33.24%  srnaMapper  srnaMapper         [.] addState
  31.00%  srnaMapper  srnaMapper         [.] mapWithoutError

Samples: 142K of event 'mem_load_uops_retired.l2_miss', Event count (approx.): 7143448989
Overhead  Command     Shared Object       Symbol
  40.79%  srnaMapper  srnaMapper          [.] mapWithoutError

Samples: 84K of event 'mem_load_uops_retired.l1_miss', Event count (approx.): 8451553539
Overhead  Command     Shared Object       Symbol
  39.11%  srnaMapper  srnaMapper          [.] mapWithoutError
```

(Using `perf record --period 10000` triggers `Workload failed: No such file or directory`.)

Comment: To me, this looks like you are waiting for memory in `mov 0x8(%rcx), %rax`, possibly even earlier up the chain.  Have you tried using cachegrind to figure out the memory access patterns?  If yes, what did it say?

Comment: @fuz No, I never tried cachegrind.  But I will.  Please, be patient...

Comment: Your code uses a lot of fairly deep indirection. Unless all of your data fits in L1$d cache, performance will suffer. In particular, whether the time is attributed to a load instruction (`mov    0x8(%rcx),%rax`) or the next instruction that *uses* the loaded value (`cmp    %rax,(%rcx)`)  is mostly a matter of taste.

Comment: @EOF So this explains why VTune attributes the time to `cmp`, and perf to `mov`... To answer you, I do not expect the data to fit in L1 cache.  The structures here are big.

Comment: @unamourdeswann If your structures do not fit into L1 cache, it becomes important to avoid indirection (particularly multiple indirection) and keep data accesses sequential in memory. Otherwise, you not only lose cache access speed, but also hardware prefetching. If your data doesn't fit into your last level cache, and is not sequential, you're going to have a very bad time, and it's absolutely not the fault of a single instruction.

Comment: @EOF Thank you.  To test this, should I use perf with `L1-dcache-loads`, `L1-dcache-stores` and `L1-dcache-prefetches`?

Comment: `-Weffc++` doesn't look like a C compilation flag. Just sayin'.

Comment: Please show relevant source code. Assembly is nice but we can generate that from the source. Somehow it doesn't work just as well the other way around.

Comment: This question is tagged c and assembly but contains neither.  The "assembly" alike pseudo code appears to be devoid of referenced labels.  From what you have it looks like you could be stalling on an unnecessary or misplaced comparison.

Comment: @n.m. I edited the code accordingly.  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @technosaurus Sorry for my poor choice of tags: I mentioned the language, but the concept is more relevant.  I will remove them.

Comment: Oh, apparently `--period` doesn't take an arg, so `10000` was interpreted as the program to run.  I didn't look at all the options in the man page to see if one of them might fix multiple events to use the same "base".

Comment: @technosaurus: that's copy-pasted disassembly output from `perf report`  (AT&T syntax because they didn't use `-Mintel`) with percentage-of-sample in the first column.  (Normalized so totals for this function add up to ~100, not as a fraction of the whole program's run time.)  You can see which direction the branches go from the arrows, and that there's one branch target (at `88:`) in the part shown, but yes we can't see the program logic other than a couple source snippets and that it's comparing 2 adjacent qwords.  That's why I answered about how to dig deeper, because that's all we can say.

Comment: Oh, now we have some actual source and a description of the context. :)

Comment: @PeterCordes Oops, sorry about that...

Comment: Perhaps try avoiding linked lists. Also what iss preprocessedInterval_t?

Comment: Updated my answer with some ideas, but it looks like a pretty thorny problem beyond just using 32-bit pointers to fit more data in the same cache footprint.  I do freelance performance-tuning consulting work (and I know a bit about bioinformatics); if you want to hire me to speed up your code I can take a deeper look, otherwise I don't see any simple clear way to speed this up.  I wouldn't expect that there's anything very easy or simple you can change in this one function.

Comment: I would love to hire you.  However, the Institution for which I work is underfinanced...  Thanks for all the comments, though!

Comment: Consider using of "restrict" keyword for those state_t  pointer parameters, if possible. It may let the compiler to do more optimization, because the compiler can assume that changes to *newState does not effect to *previousState.

Comment: @SKi Good idea!  I tried, but the time did not significantly differ (+10s, actually).

Comment: @n.m. Sorry, I forgot to answer you concerning the `preprocessedInterval_t`.  As added in the post, it is also a linked list (also cause of many cache misses, probably).

Comment: Is your code open source?  If so, include a link to the full source (ideally on github or some other VCS repo) so if anyone's interested and has the time, they can profile it themselves.  I probably won't, unfortunately; I have a dozen other things I should really be doing. :P

Comment: @PeterCordes Very good idea.  I will do!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was the sample-rate the same for branches and branch-misses?  A 50% mispredict rate would be extremely bad.

https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Period_and_rate explains that the kernel dynamically adjusts the period for each counter so events fire often enough to get enough samples even for rare events, But you can set the period (how many raw counts trigger a sample)  I think that's what `perf record --period 10000` does, but I haven't used that.

Use `perf stat` to get hard numbers.  Update: yup, your `perf stat` results confirm your branch mispredict rate is "only" 5%, not 50%, at least for the program as a whole.  That's still higher than you'd like (branches are usually frequent and mispredicts are expensive) but not insane.

---

Also for cache miss rate for L1d and maybe `mem_load_retired.l3_miss` (and/or `l2_miss` and `l1_miss`) to see if it's really that load that's missing.  e.g.

```
perf stat -etask-clock,context-switches,cpu-migrations,page-faults,cycles,branches,branch-misses,instructions,\
uops_issued.any,uops_executed.thread,\
mem_load_retired.l3_miss,mem_load_retired.l2_miss,mem_load_retired.l1_miss  ./a.out
```

You can use any of these events with `perf record` to get some statistical samples on which instructions are causing cache misses.  Those are precise events (using PEBS), so should accurately map to the correct instruction (not like "cycles" where counts get attributed to some nearby instruction, often the one that stalls waiting for an input with the ROB full, instead of the one that was slow to produce it.)

And without any skew for non-PEBS events that should "blame" a single instruction but don't always interrupt at exactly the right place.

---

If you're optimizing for your local machine and don't need it to run anywhere else, you might use `-O3 -march=native`.  Not that that will help with cache misses.

GCC profile-guided optimization can help it choose branchy vs. branchless.  (`gcc -O3 -march=native -fprofile-generate` / run it with some realistic input data to generate profile outputs / `gcc -O3 -march=native -fprofile-use`)

---

> Can I assume that branch misprediction is responsible for this slow down?

No, cache misses might be more likely.  You have a significant number of L3 misses, and going all the way to DRAM costs hundreds of core clock cycles.  Branch prediction can hide some of that *if* it predicts correctly.

> What would be the next step to optimize my code?

Compact your data structures if possible so more of them fit in cache, e.g. 32-bit pointers (Linux x32 ABI: `gcc -mx32`) if you don't need more than 4GiB of virtual address space.  Or maybe try using a 32-bit unsigned index into a large array instead of raw pointers, but that has slightly worse load-use latency (by a couple cycles on Sandybridge-family.)

And / or improve your access pattern, so you're mostly accessing them in sequential order.  So hardware prefetch can bring them into cache before you need to read them.

I'm not familiar enough with the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows%E2%80%93Wheeler_transform or its application in sequence alignment to know if it's possible to make it more efficient, but data compression is inherently problematic because you very often need data-dependent branching and accessing scattered data.  It's often worth the tradeoff vs. even more cache misses, though.

Comment: I cannot exclude that the misprediction rate is 50%.  The command used was `perf record -e branches,branch-misses mytool`. Can the same-rate be different?

Comment: @unamourdeswann: I'm not sure; use `perf stat` to get counts scaled properly by the counter rollover limit in case it's different.  Or check `perf record` options.

Comment: Fair enough.  I edited the post and gave the results.  However, I used `mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss` instead of `mem_load_retired.l3_miss` (and same for `l2` and `l1`) because I did not find the event in the list.

Comment: @unamourdeswann: Ok, for the program as a whole, you're getting only a 5% branch mispredict rate.  That's still higher than you'd like (branches are usually frequent and mispredicts are expensive) but not insane.  https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Period_and_rate explains that the kernel dynamically adjusts the period for each counter so events fire often enough to get enough samples even for rare events, But you can set the period (how many raw counts trigger a sample)  I think that's what `perf record --period 10000` does, but I haven't used that.

Comment: @unamourdeswann: I used `perf list` on perf perf version 5.0.g1c163f4 on a Skylake CPU.  Different CPUs have different event names.  `mem_load_uops_retired.l3_miss` sounds like exactly what I meant.

Comment: Pretty impressive deductions from the not too bright presentation of the problem.  If you want to know more about BWT (Burrows-Wheeler transform) and FM-Index, you can read [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2705234/), on which my work is based.

Comment: @unamourdeswann: My clues were `nucleotide` in the C code -> this is working on DNA sequences.  And I knew `bwt` might be Burrows Wheeler (heard of it in the context of bzip2 compression, which was the go-to for Linux packages / tarballs until `xz` LZMA took over).  But I wasn't sure so I just googled `bwt sequence` and the [bottom section of the BWT Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows%E2%80%93Wheeler_transform#BWT_in_bioinformatics) says something similar to the abstract of that paper you linked. :)